# How to install PixelAnnotationTool from Github?

Tags: command-line, dependencies, github

I'm an Ubuntu noob and I'm trying to install the  [PixelAnnotationTool](https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool)  on Ubuntu using the command line, but I'm having a super hard time doing it; bunch of errors, etc.

I want to know primarily **how should I install this**, and by that I mean what are the building dependencies and  how should I use the 'binaries' to install this? Which files to use? I did try the 'build' instructions on that page but it gives me errors.

:( Someone please shed some light on this

Comment: the build instructions are quite straightforward. What errors specifically are you seeing?

Answer (score 3):

### Linux AppImage

This method describes the installation without building from source. Open a terminal and type

- ```
  wget https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool/releases/download/v1.3.1/PixelAnnotationTool_x86_64_v1.3.1.AppImage
  ```
- `chmod +x PixelAnnotationTool_x86_64_v1.3.1.AppImage`
- `./PixelAnnotationTool_x86_64_v1.3.1.AppImage&` or open nautilus and double click PixelAnnotationTool_x86_64_v1.3.1.AppImage

### Build and run on linux :

Instruction follows this [link.](https://github.com/abreheret/PixelAnnotationTool/tree/master/scripts_to_build) The install the Qt5.9.1 IDE.

On Ubuntu, PixelAnnotationTool need this pacakage (OpenCV and Qt5.9.1):

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt install libopencv-dev python-opencv
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run
chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run
```

To compile the application :

```
cd ..
mkdir x64
cd x64
cmake -DQT5_DIR=/path/to/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```